# htaccess Clean URL Gives Too Many Redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the code below in my .htaccess file to remove php from the filename in the URL

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I now need to change the URL

```
editpermit.php?type=edit&id=1
```

to

```
editpermit/edit/1
```

I've added below but I get the error 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.'. Other posts say to add an `L` to the end to show it's the last line but it's not making any difference.

```
RewriteRule ^editpermit/([a-z]*)/([0-9]+)$ editpermit.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

I plan to have a few pages that will use this configuration so I need to know how to add these too at a later time

My full htaccess file is below

```
# Error pages
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 503 /503.php

# Apache Rewrite Rules
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^editpermit/([a-z]*)/([0-9]+)$ editpermit.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yep, I've added it to my original post

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
> ```

The problem is with your first "generic" rule that appends the `.php` extension. When you request `editpermit/edit/1` and `editpermit.php` exists then the second *condition* is successful (`REQUEST_FILENAME` contains `editpermit`, not `editpermit/edit/1`), but it rewrites to `editpermit/edit/1.php` based on the requested URL-path captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This then causes a rewrite loop since `editpermit/edit/1.php` also matches this rule, rewriting the request a second time to `/editpermit/edit/1.php.php` etc. etc.

You need to write the above rule like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Now you are checking the same file that you are ultimately rewriting to.

See also [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault which goes into more detail:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

(You don't need the first condition that checks the request does not map to a directory to then check that the request does map to a file.)

This can also be resolved by reversing the order of your rules (which you should do anyway). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^editpermit/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ editpermit.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

NB: I changed the quantifier that matches the 2nd path segment in the first rule from `*` to `+`. Presumably this cannot be omitted? (Although if it was it wouldn't have matched anyway.)